# Does ANTLR have a VPAT?

Tags: antlr4

Does ANTLR have a VPAT (Voluntary Product Accessibility Template) document? I tried to obtain VPAT information for ANTLR from the antlr.org website. However, I did not find any information on the antlr.org website.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR4 doesn't need a VPAT document, as it is not a graphical tool. Accessibility is about how (disabled) people can access a graphical application (mouse, keyboard, vision, colors etc.). ANTLR4, however, is a command line tool.